# C++ Vector initialization

Tags: c++, vector

I have a simple custom class, `Foo` , and I want to make a vector of `Foo` objects. In my .h file I declare the vector like this:

```
std::vector<Foo> bar;
```

I then try and initialize it to have a capacity in the .cpp file like this:

```
vector<Foo> bar;
bar.resize(10);
```

Foo has a custom constructor:

```
Foo(string name, int number)
```

Which gives me a compile error:

```
a.cpp:20:6: error: request for member 'resize' in 'bar', 
which is of non-class type 'std::vector<Foo>()'
```

How can I initialize the vector of custom objects?

Comment: This isn’t the actual code. Please post the *real* code you wrote.

Comment: Does `Foo` have a default constructor?

Comment: He probably did `vector<Foo> bar()` or something

Comment: why do you allocate your vector for he second time as `vector<Foo> bar;` in your cpp file?

Comment: @Seth Of course. But there are more things which are unclear here (re-definition of the variable? function call outside a function?) so it doesn’t pay to guess.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's why I didn't put it in an answer :)

Comment: It doesn't pay. We're here to guess for fun, not for money ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler thinks `bar` is a function (that takes no parameters and returns `vector<Foo>`), not a variable of type `vector<Foo>`.  So you have put some wrong brackets somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are creating a new object in the respective local scope, which I guess you don't want to do.

To answer the question, either put :

```
std::vector<Foo> bar;
bar.resize(10);
```

or acces the member object:

```
bar.resize(10);
```

// make sure you are including the < vector > header or using the right namespace/